# Please help me find bug

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Explanation on these two images
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

### The code

```
showUserProfile: (user_data)->
    console.log "Routers.AppRouter showUserProfile()", user_data
    window.user_profile = user_data

    playlists_both_people = user_profile['playlists']

    my_profile['playlists'].forEach (pl)-> playlists_both_people.push(pl)

    @playlists = new Playlists.Collections.PlaylistsCollection( playlists_both_people )

    $("#app").html( new Playlists.Views.User.ShowView(user_data).render().el )
    @ok()
```

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have been knowing this site for over a year still you asked such a question that can never lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now that everyone has finished beating you up, I'll be nice and show you what you're doing wrong.

You have a simple referencing problem. You start out with the `user_data` object being passed to your function. Then you make another reference to what `user_data` points at here:

```
window.user_profile = user_data
```

Now your data looks like this:

```
window.user_profile ->-+
                       |
                       +->- {playlists: [ ], ...}
                       |
user_data ----------->-+
```

Then you make another reference to `user_data.playlists` here:

```
playlists_both_people = user_profile['playlists']
```

And now you have this on your hands:

```
window.user_profile ->-+
                       |
                       +->- {playlists: [ ], ...}
                       |      ^
user_data ----------->-+      |
                              |
playlists_both_people --->----+
```

And then you push a bunch of things onto the `playlists_both_people` array and wonder why it changed `user_data.playlists` as well. The diagram tells you why: you never made a copy of anything, you're just referencing the same piece of data through multiple variables.

You're using Backbone so you have Underscore, perhaps [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) can help you:

```
playlists_both_people = _(user_profile['playlists']).clone()
```

That will give you a (shallow) copy of `user_profile.playlists` (which is the same as `user_data.playlists` at this point) in `playlists_both_people` and the next `forEach` won't change anything in `user_data`.

Note that you still might have a double reference problem with `window.user_profile`. You can't use just one `_.clone` to fix this possible problem though, you'd have to clone each member separately since `_.clone` only does shallow copies. However, you probably have jQuery around and [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) supports deep copying so that might be an option.

I'd also recommend against putting things directly in `window`. You'd be better off setting up a namespace for your application, say `window.app`, and then use that namespace:

```
window.app.user_profile = ...
```